# How do i click on the "Close" browser button on top right of the page with Selenium Webdrive?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

In the application i am testing, i am inputting some data in some fields in Chrome Browser with Selenium. I want to click on the "Close" button on the top right of the page, because a notification should appear when i try to do that. However, i cannot find a way to click on that

Is there any way to simulate clicking on the "X" button in the top right of the screen?

I tried to close the browser with driver.close() but that closes the browser immediately. I need to emulate the user action of clicking on the "X" button top right.

Comment: Please share all your code including the link to the page you working on. Currently this question is missing minimal debugging details

Comment: You can't use selenium to click on UI buttons, you must use Automaton or something similar

Comment: i am talking about automation, java with selenium. so i need a method that would click on the Close button of the browser. @Prophet there is no debug information needed, i need a method to click on the X (close) button of the browser. After that i can easily write an assertion for the alert that i need to see.

Comment: @prophet the page does not matter. let's presume the page is google.com, i just navigated to it. now i want to click on the close button of the browser. how do it do it?

Comment: Generally you need to get the element and click it. That's all. Like this `driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("span.grid-header-name-text")).click()`.

Comment: @Prophet that is not the proper selector for the close button. i know how to locate an element on a page. the challenge is to click on the close button, which is not part of the page, but rather part of the browser.

Comment: This is exactly what I wrote you 36 minutes ago

Comment: it is not working. 
org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"span.grid-header-name-text"}
  (Session info: chrome=109.0.5414.75)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the X mark is outside the scope of HTML tree structure, you cannot inspect element and get the locator of it. And hence you cannot achieve the action of clicking X using selenium(unless you want to go with `driver.close()` or `driver.quit()`). You can try by using either some third party tool or by using java's features like Robot class. Try below code:

```
driver = new ChromeDriver();
driver.manage().window().maximize();
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
driver.get("https://www.facebook.com/");
Robot robot = new Robot();
Thread.sleep(2000);
// Press keys Ctrl + W
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_W);
// Release keys Ctrl + W
robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_W);
robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
```

Try this. **Note**: Ctrl+W shortcut is to close chrome browser, if you want to close some other browser, use the shortcut accordingly